# Java Print cannot set paper size

Tags: java, linux, printing, cups

I am trying to set the paper size to be landscape A5.
I am printing from a java application, using the default PrinterJob procedure.
I am also printing to cups-pdf.
My problem is, no matter what I try, I cannot change the page format to A4 or A5 or whatever ... it is stuck to US Letter.

My question is:
is this an OS problem? or related to java ????

When I call

```
PageFormat pf = job.pageDialog(pf)
```

The dialog even wouldn't show any other option but US Letter

Update:
When I try to print from Command Line, using lp... I can print any size very easily... but I want to do that from within Java...

Comment: You ,at need to take advantage of the [Print Services API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/services.html)

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558152/how-can-i-print-a-custom-paper-size-cheques-8-x-4/13558335#13558335) might provide some more info about setting the page size..

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer .. I'll check the example, do some reading... then get back to you...

Comment: @MadProgrammer ... Thank you so much.... you could make your comment as answer please.. that solved my problem..