# Java print, Letter format instead of A4

Tags: java, printing, printers

As far as I know, `Java` Print uses the OS (windows) settings (format type) when sending a task to the printer. However, no matter how I change my code and despite the fact that all my settings are set for an A4, after sending a task to the printer it always accepts the task with a Letter format and I get a printer out of paper error. Although, when I press the restart printing button on the printer it prints out the file correctly. I have tried a lot of different methods from StackOverflow but they didn't really work out. I tried my application on another PC connected to the same model of printer - same problem. Maybe I'm missing something small or looking for the solution in the wrong place?

This is a piece of my code:

```
private PrinterJob createPDFPrinterJob(PDDocument pdfDocument) {

    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
    pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);

    Paper paper = new Paper();
    pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

    try {
        printJob.setPrintable(new PDPageable(pdfDocument), pageFormat);
    }
    catch(PrinterException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return printJob;
}
```

Comment: You can make your own `Paper`, something like [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558152/how-can-i-print-a-custom-paper-size-cheques-8-x-4/13558335#13558335)

Comment: Have you tried `PrintJob.defaultPage()`?  I'd also have a look at the default properties of `Paper`

Comment: I did a quick test and `Paper` seems to default to Letter, but `PrintJob.defaultPage().getPaper` seems to be in A4 (which would support my current printers settings)

Comment: You could also use `PrintJob.pageDialog` to see what the properties of a particular `PageFormat` are

Comment: @charith-prabhagya please do not write such long and senseless comments to your edits as this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I did a quick test using:

```
Paper paper = new Paper();
```

Which generates a page of 21.59x27.94 cms, which is consistent with Letter

I then had a look at:

```
PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage().getPaper()
```

Which generates a page of 21x29.7 cms, which is consistent with A4.

So, my recommendation would be to use the `PrinterJob`'s default `PageFormat` as a bases of your work